# why do I get a 404 error when I want to install android-sdk via yaourt on my archlinux 64?

Tags: android, archlinux

I was trying to config my android dev environment on my archlinux 64, I followed the [wiki of archlinux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Android) here, set up my multilib and then yaourt -S android-sdk. I didn' t edit the PKUBUILD or android-sdk.install, but I get a 404 error when I was trying to download android-sdk_r18-linux.tgz.
I don't know why I get an error like this.

Answer (score 1):

It's seem that the url of android-sdk in PKGBUILD is broken. 
You can find the correct url and replace it.
After that, you may want to run `makepkg -g` to generate correct md5sums.

Comment: Thanks, I have fixed that problem, it is the reason of GFW in China. The developer site of android is blocked by GFW